# Use variables in pattern matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have the following:

```
if (mobile.matches("[0-9]{6,20}")) {
   ...
}
```

But would like to replace the {6,20} with variable values due to them been dynamic in some cases.

I.e.

```
int minValue = 11;
int maxValue = 20

if (mobile.matches("[0-9]{minValue,maxValue}")) {
   ...
}
```

How can I include variables in the Reg Exp?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use Java's simple string concatenation, using the plus sign.

```
if (mobile.matches("[0-9]{" + minValue + "," + maxValue + "}")) {
```

Indeed, as Michael suggested compiling it is better for performance if you use it a lot.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{" + minValue + "," + maxValue + "}");
```

Then use it when needed like this:

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(mobile);
if (m.matches()) {
```

Comment: You can precompile the regex matcher if you're going to use it frequently and the values will not change.

Comment: That works, I just thought there might be some other recommended way. Cheers Martijn...and Andy.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `String.format("[0-9]{%s,%s}", minValue, maxValue)`