# How to do string matches till specific character like @

Tags: java

I have an array of the string with text and URLs (urlsArray) like:

```
text1@http://url1
text2,text3@http://url2
text3,text4,text5@http://url3
```

I need to return the URLs where the text before @ contains text3

I am trying something like

```
for (String string : urlsArray){
    if(string.matches("WHAT SHOULD BE HERE TO SEARCH FOR text3 till @")){
        List<String> redirectURL = Arrays.asList(string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("@") + 1));
       System.out.println(redirectURL);
    }
}
```

So the question is

```
if(string.matches("WHAT SHOULD BE HERE TO SEARCH FOR text3 till @")){
```

Expected output is:

```
http://url2
http://url3
```

or any other method beside string matches

How can I use variable instead of text3 in

```
String patternString = ".*text3.*@.*";
```

Comment: You already used `string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("@") + 1)`. Matching up to the character is equivalent to just using the other side of the substring, so `string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf("@"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regex to check if the string contains text3

```java
        String patternString = ".*text3.*@.*";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        boolean matches = matcher.matches();
        if (matches) {
          ...
        }
```

if you want to check also if the substring is actually an url you can use you can use this regex

```
regex = “((http|https)://)(www.)?” 
+ “[a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#?&//=]{2,256}\\.[a-z]” 
+ “{2,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#?&//=]*)”
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works, one queestion , how can I use variable instead of text3 in 
String patternString = ".*text3.*@.*";

Comment: @behador1354 you can refer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317603/use-variables-in-pattern-matcher

Answer (score 0):

With Java streams you can split, check and print like this:

```
Stream.of(urlsArray)
    .map(u -> u.split("@"))
    .filter(a -> a[0].contains("text3"))
    .forEach(a -> System.out.println(a[1]));
```